# Can we know OS from EXIF data?

Tags: android, ios, ipad, exif

When users upload pictures to their profile, have solved the problem of file and dimensions restriction (memory limit) using php/GD by using Imagick.

Now need to find out how to rotate based on cell/image device, as Android and Apple assign different orientation values.

Android = value 1 is with Samsung S5 horizontal with speaker to the left and "shutter button" to right.

Apple - value 1 is with iPAD 3 horizontal with camera and "shutter button" to the right.

Wondering if the EXIF data has o/s of device. I know the Make and model are available.

Have noticed this value  - IFD0.Exif_IFD_Pointer: 38 - appears for iPad 3 and -IFD0.Exif_IFD_Pointer: 234 - for Samsung S5.

Cannot find a listing for Exif_IFD_Pointer table/list to see if this a device list

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think so. I find exiftool to be a very complete exif reader, and it doesn't mention any operating system tags. [This document](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-ExifTool/lib/Image/ExifTool/TagNames.pod#EXIF_Tags) contains exiftool's full library of tags (starting from the standard EXIF tags).

Comment: Note also that the orientation tag is explicitly codified in [the spec](https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js/blob/master/spec/Exif2-2.pdf?raw=true) (see page 24). You shouldn't be getting inconsistent results from different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the Orientation EXIF Tag device independent?

http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html

As far as I know the smartphones don't store the OS on the EXIF tags, but with the Make and Model EXIF data you have enough information to obtained the OS.